# Difference between position vector and distance vector?

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics

Its similarities and dissimilarities between position vector and distance vector?

Comment: Welcome to mathstackexcange. A question, especially this one, require some context, otherwise it's really difficult to give a pertinent answer.

Answer (score 1):

A position vector tells you where you are at a point in space whereas a direction vector simply tells you the direction in which you are going. A direction vector is also required to have unit length and is the position vector divided by its absolute value.

For example, the vector $v=(3,4,5)$ is a position vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its corresponding direction vector is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}}(3,4,5)$